# Patternmatching for empty List in Haskell

Tags: haskell

as i am new to Haskell i am not quite familiar with everything. i tried to implement a function using pattern matching but this wont work as it gives the following Exception: Prelude.head empty list. This is the code sample:

```
swapListToTowers::[[Bool]]->[[Bool]]
swapListToTowers [] = []
swapListToTowers xs = [head x| x <-xs]:swapListToTowers (cutOfFirstElements xs)


cutOfFirstElements::[[Bool]]->[[Bool]]
cutOfFirstElements [] = []
cutOfFirstElements xs = [tail x | x <- xs]
```

I think the case for capturing the empty list does not quite work , does it?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What is the goal of your function? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're missing a pattern to match your inner list, so when you get to your list comprehension, there hasn't been a check to see if your inner list is empty

I'm not sure what your function is designed to do, but you might want to split out your functions a bit like this so you can deal with the empty sublist on it's own

```
swapListToTowers::[[Bool]]->[[Bool]]
swapListToTowers [] = []
swapListToTowers xs = swapListToTowersInner (head xs) : ...

swapListToTowersInner :: [Bool] -> [Bool]
swapListToTowersInner [] = []
swapListToTowersInner xs = head xs

... similarly here for cutOfFirstElements
```

Answer (score 3):

Both functions take as arguments list of lists. The empty list match `[]` only matches the outer list, but not the case where the outer list is non-empty, but the inner list isn't; e.g. `[[]]`.